# php ajax database question

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, select

I am trying to understand how do I modify the example in this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp so that the database is queried for multiple selections. I mean, if more than one option is selected (by adding the "multiple" keyword to the form), how do I do a database query for these multiple selections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without looking at that page, to send multiple values from a select, just add `[]` right after the name field: `<select multiple="multiple" name="foo[]">`.

The request array ($_GET or $_POST in PHP) will contain a key 'foo' which maps to multiple 'selected' values. Once you have modified your page, to get a clearer idea of what is going on, just do:

```
print_r($_GET['foo']); // or $_POST, whichever
```

Then you will just need to modify the server script to store (or do whatever) with the set of received values.

The following example demonstrates how to create a string from the multiple selected values, by registering an onchange handler to the select element:

```
document.getElementById("theSelect").onchange = function() {
    var len = this.options.length;
    var selected = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(this.options[i].selected) {
            selected.push(this.options[i].value);
        } 
    }
    alert(selected);
    //so you can do something like getUsers(selected.join(","));
};
```

**[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/wREZv/2/)**

Comment: I did change the form to  <select name="acad_year[]" onchange="showUser(this.value)" multiple> . My problem is how do I chnage the javascript on the client side in that example to send the multiple selection.

Comment: Also, if you go with that approach, you won't be needing the brackets after the name thingie.

Comment: Thank you karim. You have saved my day. That is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same. The difference is that when you send data to server, you send a list of name. Then you can use php in server to build the HTML and return it.

Comment: yeah, how do I modify the client side javascript in that example to send the array of selected options?

Answer (score 0):

if ur using checkboxes try using POST method instead of GET

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","getuser.php",true);

<input tabindex="3" type="checkbox" name="gender[]" id="gender" value="M">Male
<input tabindex="4" type="checkbox" name="gender[]" id="gender" value="F">Female

try print_r($_POST);
```

Thanks
Sanil